# Нужен ли предлог?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Предложение такое: "...причем, в нашем море, а не (в) Балтийском". Я почему-то засомневался: нужен второй раз предлог В или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"На слух" хочется с предлогом.

Причем в красном платье, а не синем (?) *хочется вставить "в"*
Причем в комнате, а не кухне (тут уж точно нужен предлог!)

Answer (score 0):

И после слова **причем** запятая не нужна. Это союз, а не вводное слово. (Мое дополнение адресовано Amano, задавшему(ей) вопрос.)

Comment: "И" означает, что предлог все же нужен? Ура, я правильно написала!

Answer (score 0):

Грамматически предлог не требуется. Но хороший корректор обязательно его вставит. Экономия на предлогах - одна из типичнх стилистических ошибок.

Comment: Вот точно, хорошо, что Вы это сказали! Есть грамматика, а есть еще и забота о читателе, чтобы ему не "продираться" сквозь замысловатые конструкции.  

В качестве юмора - одна из (реальных) вывесок:  
"Отдел по работе с молодежью аппарата главы администрации города Казани". Слегка оглушает, не правда ли!